# Show the hypothesis

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Im stuck on on how to draw the conclusion for this question.

Show that:

p->q

(¬p-r)^(r->s)

---

∴(¬q->s)

p: "You will send me an email"
q: "I will finish the assignment"
r: "I will go to sleep early"
s: "I will wake up feeling refreshed"

In plain English it is quite easy to understand however proving it in terms of discrete math has been quite the trouble for me.

Thank you in advanced for your help, it is much appreciated!!

Comment: Maybe there is a typo in the scond formula...

Comment: The details depend on the proof system you are using... You may contrapose the first premise to get $(\lnot q \to \lnot p)$ and then assume $\lnot q$.